# Quiz form with random questions

Tags: php, quiz

How could I make this code more efficient?  Instead of using many `if`-statements, should I make a function, array, or `switch`?  How would I do that?

```
<form method="post" action="trivia2.php">
<ol>
<li>How many days are in a week? <input type="text" name="daysweek"></li>
<li>How many days are in a year? <input type="text" name="daysyear"></li>
<li>How many weeks are in a year? <input type="text" name="weeksyear"></li>
<li>What color is the sky? <input type="text" name="colorsky"></li>
<li>what is us president name? <input type="text" name="presidentname"></li>
<li>How many sides does a triangle have? <input type="text" name="sidestriange"></li>
<li>What is the first element on the periodic table of elements? <input type="text" name="firstelement"></li>
<li>Bees create what sweet substance? <input type="text" name="beesubstance"></li>
<li>How many stripes are displayed on the American flag?<input type="text" name="stripes"></li>
</ol>
<input type="submit" value="Done!"/>
</form>
<?php
$daysweek=$_POST['daysweek'];
$daysyear=$_POST['daysyear'];
$weeksyear=$_POST['weeksyear'];
$colorsky=$_POST['colorsky'];
$presidentname=$_POST['presidentname'];
$sidestriangle=$_POST['sidestriange'];
$firstelement=$_POST['firstelement'];
$beesubstance=$_POST['beesubstance'];
$stripes=$_POST['stripes'];
$wrong=0;
if($daysweek==7){
echo "1. you got the right answer: $daysweek<br/>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 1 is wrong<br/>";}

if($daysyear==365){
echo "2. you got the right answer: $daysyear<br/>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 2 is wrong<br/>";}

if($weeksyear==52){
echo "3. you got the right answer: $weeksyear<br/>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 3 is wrong<br/>";}

if($colorsky=='blue'){
echo "4. you got the right answer: $colorsky<br/>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 4 is wrong<br/>";}

if($presidentname=='obama'){
echo "5. you got the right answer: $presidentname</br>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 5 is wrong<br/>";}

if($sidestriangle==3){
echo "6. you got the right answer: $sidestriangle</br>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 6 is wrong<br/>";}

if($firstelement=='hydrogen'){
echo "7. you got the right answer: $firstelement<br/>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 7 is wrong<br/>";}

if($beesubstance=='honey'){
echo "8. you got the right answer: $beesubstance<br/>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 8 is wrong<br/>";}

if($stripes==13){
echo "9. you got the right answer: $stripes<br/>";
}else {
    $wrong++;
    echo "number 9 is wrong<br/>";}
echo "<h3>You have $wrong wrong answers</h3>";
?>
```

Comment: Security should be a far greater concern here.

Comment: The answer to #2 is incorrect on leap years, but I digress.

Answer (score 1):

Theres nothing particularly unefficient about what you have, but there are a couple of things. instead of storing the variables like

```
$daysweek=$_POST['daysweek'];
```

just leave them in `$_POST` like

```
if($_POST['daysweek']==7){//..
```

and then instead of

```
echo "1. you got the right answer: $daysweek<br/>";
```

you already know the answer is 7 so just

```
echo "1. you got the right answer: 7<br/>";
```

but based on the content of your application you are not yet in a place where you need to be worrying about optimization

Comment: I think what Seth gave is nearly as far as it gets to save some resources, on the other hand it is a bad habit to use a variable if you are not 100% sure if it exists.

Comment: if `$_POST['daysweek']` does not exist, neither will `$daysweek=$_POST['daysweek']`

Answer (score 0):

How about this.. To add or remove answers, all you would have to do is change the `$answers` array making the code easy to maintain.

```
$answers = [
            "daysweek" => 365,
            "daysyear" => 365
           ];

$answerNumber = 1;
$wrong = 0;

foreach($answers as $key => $value){

  if(checkAnswer($key)){
    echo "$answerNumber. you got the right answer: $value<br/>";

  } else {
    $wrong++;

  }

  $answerNumber++;

}

function checkAnswer($key){
  return $_POST[$key] == $answers[$key] ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: can u please explain me this line:
return $_POST[$key] == $answers[$key] ? TRUE : FALSE;
what does ? True: FALSE mean?

Comment: @HamDlink `? :` is a conditional operator more or like `if else`. This is same as writing `if($_POST[$key] == $answers[$key]) { echo "TRUE"; } else { echo "FALSE"; }` , the former one saves a lot of code writing but both serve the same purpose.

Comment: Why not remove the `? TRUE : FALSE` completely? `==` returns a boolean anyway.